AttributeError: module 'pyarrow.lib' has no attribute 'Bool8Type'

Hello. When I try to import the Dask DataFrame for my student project,
the following error appears. I have basically tried updating
everything and reinstalling. I use a Jupyter Notebook in vsc with a
conda environment.

Code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as pxc
import re
from dask.distributed import LocalCluster, Client
from dask import dataframe as dd

Output:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 9
      7 import re
      8 from dask.distributed import LocalCluster, Client
----> 9 from dask import dataframe as dd

File c:\Users\tu\.conda\envs\pythonAD\Lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\__init__.py:108
    105 except ImportError:
    106     pass
--> 108 if _dask_expr_enabled():
    109     import dask_expr as dd
    111     # trigger loading of dask-expr which will in-turn import dask.dataframe and run remainder
    112     # of this module's init updating attributes to be dask-expr
    113     # note: needs reload, in case dask-expr imported before dask.dataframe; works fine otherwise

File c:\Users\tu\.conda\envs\pythonAD\Lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\__init__.py:33, in _dask_expr_enabled()
     31         return (DASK_EXPR_ENABLED := False)
     32     try:
---> 33         import dask_expr  # noqa: F401
     34     except ImportError:
     35         msg = """
     36 Dask dataframe query planning is disabled because dask-expr is not installed.
     37 
     38 You can install it with `pip install dask[dataframe]` or `conda install dask`.
     39 This will raise in a future version.
     40 """

File c:\Users\tu\.conda\envs\pythonAD\Lib\site-packages\dask_expr\__init__.py:3
      1 import dask.dataframe
----> 3 from dask_expr import _version, datasets
      4 from dask_expr._collection import *
      5 from dask_expr._dispatch import get_collection_type

File c:\Users\tu\.conda\envs\pythonAD\Lib\site-packages\dask_expr\datasets.py:8
      5 import pandas as pd
      6 from dask.dataframe.utils import pyarrow_strings_enabled
----> 8 from dask_expr._collection import new_collection
      9 from dask_expr._expr import ArrowStringConversion
     10 from dask_expr.io import BlockwiseIO, PartitionsFiltered

File c:\Users\tu\.conda\envs\pythonAD\Lib\site-packages\dask_expr\_collection.py:69
     67 from pandas.api.types import is_scalar as pd_is_scalar
     68 from pandas.api.types import is_timedelta64_dtype
---> 69 from pyarrow import fs as pa_fs
     70 from tlz import first
     72 import dask_expr._backends  # noqa: F401

File c:\Users\tu\.conda\envs\pythonAD\Lib\site-packages\pyarrow\fs.py:53
     50     _not_imported.append("HadoopFileSystem")
     52 try:
---> 53     from pyarrow._gcsfs import GcsFileSystem  # noqa
     54 except ImportError:
     55     _not_imported.append("GcsFileSystem")

File c:\Users\tu\.conda\envs\pythonAD\Lib\site-packages\pyarrow\_gcsfs.pyx:1, in init pyarrow._gcsfs()

AttributeError: module 'pyarrow.lib' has no attribute 'Bool8Type'

I hope somebody knows more about this error.

How did you install this environment? Did you only used pip or Conda also? What command did you use?
